# XPathによるテーブルデータを取得したい

Tags: xpath

XPATHを使用してテーブルデータの取得を行いたいと考えています。
テーブルデータは、以下の通りです。
このとき、以下の通り入力すれば「人数」や「平均身長」を指定できますが、その下にある「5」「170」を取得する方法がわからず、質問させていただきます。

```
/table/tr[td[contains(normalize-space(),"平均身長")]]
```

※ 「人数」と「平均身長」の数字データを""内を除きすべて同じXPATHを用いたいと考えています。

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>人数</td>
    <td>平均身長</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>170</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: `preceding-sibling` と `count` を使って `/table/tr[2]/td[count(/table/tr/td[contains(.,"平均身長")]/preceding-sibling::*)+1]` な感じでしょうか。

Comment: ブラボー！いけました！ありがとうございます！！天才！

Answer (score 1):

XPath 2.0だとこんな風にも書けますよ．

```
for $i in 1 to count(/table/tr[1]/td) return if (contains(/table/tr[1]/td[$i],'平均体重')) then string(/table/tr[2]/td[$i]) else ()
```

**Xygen 20.0でのXPath/XQuery Builderでの実行画面:**

[image: oXygen 20.0での実行画面]

御参考まで．

［追伸］
`index-of`を使うのが一番簡単なんじゃないか？と思います．例えば

```
/table/tr[2]/td[index-of(/table/tr[1]/td/string(.),'平均体重')]/string(.)
```

**以下同様の実行画面:**

[image: oXygen 20.0での実行画面]

Comment: コメントありがとうございます　2.0があるんですね！初めて知りました…　よりプログラミングチックになってるのでわかりやすくできそうですね　Nokogiriでも使えるか調べてできそうなら挑戦してみます！